# Is it possible to specify which commits to clone with git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am using `.gitmodules` file to specify a git submodule for my main repo:

```yaml
[submodule "SUBMODULE"]
    path = ...
    url = ...
```

And then in the command line: `git clone MAINREPO --recursive`.

Is it possible to specify which commit of the submodule to check out **in the cloning command**?

Comment: You mean one different than the one committed in the top repo ?

Comment: Yes, any specific one from the history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: No way. The information is written in the superproject in commits that stores info about submodule change. Every time one runs

```
git clone --recursive superproject-url
```

or

```
git checkout --recursive some-old-commit
```

Git looks up commits of submodules in the HEAD or the old commit being checked out and checkout stored commits of the submodules.

If you want to change what commit is stored in the HEAD: go to the locally cloned submodule, checkout the commit, return to the superproject, add and commit the change in the submodule, push:

```
cd subdir
git checkout branch-tag-or-ID
cd .. # back to the superproject
git add subdir
git commit -m "Change in subdir" subdir
```

If the commit in the submodule you want to change to is the HEAD you can do instead in the superproject

```
git submodule update --remote subdir
git commit -m "Change in subdir" subdir
```

Instead of a command line options you can do (with a shell script or a git alias) `git clone --recursive && cd subdir && git checkout commit-ID`. That's the only way. something like

```
# .gitconfig
[alias]
clone-sub = "!f() { git clone --recursive \"$1\" && cd \"$2\" && git checkout \"$3\"; }; f"
```

Usage: `git clone-sub superproject-url submodule-path commit-ID`

Comment: Thank you, but this does not really answer my question. I am wondering if there is a command flag / hack to add such that the cloned superproject will contain the submodule of a specified commit. One time I clone with `XXX` version of the latter, 2 minutes later I clone with `YYY` version of the latter. All this parametrized from the command line.

Comment: The answer to your question is: No way. The commit of the submodules is stored in the superproject. The only way to change that is to commit and push the superproject. With changed `.gitmodules` you have to commit and push anyway. Instead of any command line options you can just do (with a shell script or a git alias) `git clone --recursive && cd subdir && git checkout commit-ID`. That's the only way.

Comment: Alright, could you please append the comment above to the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @maciek Done. I also added a draft for such an alias.